# Getting error when trying to run a python script from AWS codebuild which builds an image using Docker sdk for python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

I am trying to run a python script from AWS codebuild which which builds an image using Docker sdk for python.
There are project specific reasons to put this code in a python file and not directly codebuild job.
However I am getting the error :

```
('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1285, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1331, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1040, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.9.16/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Docker is present in the machine as running `docker --version` is giving the correct result.
Also running the same python script is working fine from local machine.

Comment: That backtrace looks like it means the Docker socket doesn't exist.  Is the build happening locally, or in an AWS hosted environment (and if it's remote, does the remote environment have a usable Docker daemon)?

Comment: If this is running in CodeBuild, then showing your CodeBuild configuration in your question would be extremely relevant. `docker --version` working just means `docker` is installed, it doesn't mean it is available and running as a service. To perform docker builds inside a CodeBuild job it has to be configured to run in `privileged` mode, because CodeBuild jobs themselves are docker containers, so `privileged` mode is required for docker-in-docker.

Comment: @MarkB thanks for your answer, setting the priviliged mode worked fine for me